# How can I write a prepare() method in Storm bolts using Java?

Tags: java, apache-storm

I want to read a file from `Bolt.prepare()` and pass the object of the file read to the execute method. Can any one post me sample code how to do it in the Storm bolts using Java? I am using:

```
public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context) {
    try {
        this.context = context;
        this.fileReader = new FileInputStream("/home/anji/all-users.csv");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        /*throw new RuntimeException("Error reading file "
                + conf.get("inputFile"));*/
    }
    this.collector = collector;

}
```

I am calling the `FileReader` in the `execute()` method: `User p = new User(fileReader);`

Error Message:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
  at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
  at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:272)
  at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
  at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
  at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
  at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
  at com.csvreader.CsvReader.checkDataLength(Unknown Source)
  at com.csvreader.CsvReader.readRecord(Unknown Source)
  at com.csvreader.CsvReader.readHeaders(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "PrepareMethod()"? The method Bolt.prepare(...)?

Comment: sorry for the wrong typing its Bolt.prepare()

Comment: I don't understand the semantics exactly. Do you want to read the whole file at once? Or do you want to read a single line per input tuple? How do the "User" objects relate to the input tuples? Or are the "Users" the only input data you want to process?

Comment: Actually FileReader has 2lac word list. User is class which uses the FileReader and computes to the input tuple. That is for each input tuple, the tuple checks the wordlist if  words in the tuple has any matches with the word list it returns those matched words.

Comment: I assume, that the first tuple is processed correctly and the exception occurs for the second tuple... You need to reset the FileReader to be able to read the file again: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#reset%28%29 Does this solve the problem? (Btw: I would recommend, to read all Users into main memory in prepare() and do the comparison as an in memory operation (instead of reading the same file again for each incoming tuple). Or is the file too large to be stored in memory?

Comment: Is your problem solved? How?

Comment: Thanks,I solved my error but the problem is, I added all the word list to the arraylist in the prepare method. since I has to do some pre-processing of the words. Now I am comparing the each incoming tuple with the arraylist.I'm facing the terrible latency problem in this bolt. Any suggestions

Comment: What kind of comparison do you do? How many users to you have in your list? Can you sort the list or users and do a binary search instead of a linear scan?

Answer (score 2):

Just use a member variable in your Bolt that contains all `User`. Read the file only a single time in `prepare()`:

```
public class MyClass implements IRichBolt {
    private final List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    public void prepare(...) {
        File f = new File(...);
        // open file and create objects (or similar code)
       String line;
       while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           users.add(new Users(line));
       }
    }

    // other methods including .execute(...) can use users 
}
```

Comment: I just added this as an answer to make it clear (because it was hidden in my comment).

Comment: If your logic requires complex comparison, I guess there is nothing you can do about it. At least, it's no a Storm related problem. That's regular Java stuff you need to get faster...

Comment: Iam using same code in the prepare() method here text is input tuple
In execute() Method
`List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i=0; i<users.size(); i++) {
  if (text.matches(".*\\b" + users.get(i) + "\\b.*")) {
  
    if (!titles.contains(users.get(i)))
     titles.add(users.get(i));
   }
  }
  return(titles.toString());
 }`

I am sending the titles to next Bolt. Lot of Latency

Comment: What do you actually mean by "Lot of Latency". Can you put a number on it? And as i just told you. Your comparison logic is quite complex. Matching and comparing Strings is expensive. There is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Well, this number sounds reasonable. If guess you have multiple thousands User to compare with and you predicate is complex and thus compute intensive. Nevertheless, I assume that I answered your initial question. If no, please tell me why.

Comment: I was wondering just about this, I had a 5200MS latency and a “Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded”, because i was calling the reader on the execute(tuple), creating a lot of readers, now I understand that the prepare method is the one where I should do that, because it executes once on the Bolt instantiation; thanks both for the answer and question. Latenci about 900 ms now, that's much better.

Comment: Glad that it helped you! Thanks for the feedback! :)